# Views throw an Ajax error in the admin page

Tags: 7, views

When I go to a View edit page in the admin of Drupal 7, two of them (one that's called front page and was already there, and one that's a jcarousel) throw an error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /admin/structure/views/view/frontpagecarousel/preview/page/ajax
StatusText: error
ResponseText:
```

"ResponseText" is followed by a huge load of unformatted text (not even a newline character). But I believe that it must have something to do with the "Path", which I don't believe exists. I'm not certain, but I think this is interfering with jCarousel's options, as it expects something to appear in the Fields section, but the Fields section says "The selected style or row format does not utilize fields."

So, what's going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem many times before. For me, it was because I had the `theme developer` module enabled. I think the `firebug` module has the same effect. Basically, they are both adding extra markup to the response text and it isn't able to parse it then.

Comment: I don't have either of those, but it sounds like it could be any module that adds to the response text. Unfortunately, the problem seemed to mysteriously vanish a while back, but it had already been a while, and I can't tell what changes fixed it.